# Explosion doesn't show up in rendered frames

Tags: rendering, particles, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3t4g5WsUbY

...Rendering in eevee. The explosion looks good enough when I play it in blender, but when I render it the frames are empty.

I don't know what info is relevant here so I'll just post the blend file (although one thing I suspect is that I can't check the 'Volumetrics' checkbox like in the video, it doesn't have on on my version)

[image]